# Slicing a pointer to slice

Tags: go

When I'm following this [golang blog post](http://blog.golang.org/slices)  about arrays and slices, I tried to pass a **pointer to a slice** to a function that modify the underlying `len` property in the slice header:

```
func PtrSubtractOneFromLength(slicePtr *[]byte) {
    slice := *slicePtr
    *slicePtr = slice[0 : len(slice)-1]
}
```

And when I tried to refactor it to this from:

```
func PtrSubtractOneFromLength(slicePtr *[]int) {
    *slicePtr = *slicePtr[0 : len(*slicePtr)-1]
}
```

I get this error

```
cannot slice slicePtr (type *[]int)
```

Where is the magic in the `slice := *slicePtr` statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slice expression binds stronger than a dereference. Try this:

```
*slicePtr = (*slicePtr)[0 : len(*slicePtr)-1]
```

Comment: Thanks @FUZxxl  Where can I read this in the golang spec document ?

Comment: @tarrsalah That's a bit tricky. Syntactically, a slice or index expression takes a `PrimaryExpr` and creates a `PrimaryExpr` whereas unary `*` is an operator that takes a `UnaryExpr` and creates a `UnaryExpr`. A `PrimaryExpr` can become an `UnaryExpr` but not the other way round which explains these precedence rules. It's all over the place in the spec, nowhere in particular to point you too.